# Creating an evaluate function in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

[image]
Example of what function should do:
(list 3 4 6 9 7) ←→ 3x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 9x + 7

What I have so far:

```
(define (poly-eval x numlist)
(compute-poly-tail x numlist 0 0))

(define (compute-poly-tail xn list n acc)
    (cond
      [(null? list) acc]
    [else (compute-poly-tail (first list) (rest list)
                       (+ acc (* (first list) (expt xn n))) (+ n 1))]))



(check-expect(poly-eval 5 (list 1 0 -1)) 24)
(check-expect(poly-eval 0 (list 3 4 6 9 7)) 7)
(check-expect(poly-eval 2 (list 1 1 0 1 1 0))  54)
```

Expected results:

```
(check-expect(poly-eval 5(list 1 0 -1)) 24)
(check-expect(poly-eval  0 (list 3 4 6 9 7))7)
(check-expect(poly-eval 2 (list 1 1 0 1 1 0)) 54)
```

I am getting a run-time error. Can someone spot what I am doing wrong. I don't know why I am getting these results.

Comment: I don't understand what the `xn` argument is doing. It starts out as `x`, so I was expecting it to stay as the same value of `x` the whole time, but instead on the recursive call it gets `(first list)`. Then how do the next terms still know what `x` is?

Comment: The next thing I don't understand is `n`. `n` starts out as zero, but for polynomials with the most-significant term first, I would expect `n` to start out as the degree of the polynomial, like if it's `x^2 + 2*x + 1` I would expect `n` to start out as `2`, and go down by one on every recursive call

Comment: Then you're putting `acc` as the last argument, so I'm guessing the `(+ acc ....)` expression should also go as the last argument is the recursive call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the code:

- You need to process the coefficient's list in the correct order, corresponding to their position in the polynomial! you can either:

  - `reverse` the list from the beginning and process the coefficients from right to left (simpler).
  - Or start `n` in `(sub1 (length numlist))` and *decrease* it at each iteration (that's what I did).
- The order and value of the arguments when calling the recursion in `compute-poly-tail` is incorrect, check the procedure definition, make sure that you pass along the values in the same order as you defined them, also the first call to `(first list)` doesn't make any sense.
- You should not name `list` a parameter, this will clash with the built-in procedure of the same name. I renamed it to `lst`.

This should fix the issues:

```
(define (poly-eval x numlist)
  (compute-poly-tail x numlist (sub1 (length numlist)) 0))

(define (compute-poly-tail xn lst n acc)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) acc]
    [else (compute-poly-tail xn
                             (rest lst)
                             (- n 1)
                             (+ acc (* (first lst) (expt xn n))))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(poly-eval 5 (list 1 0 -1))
=> 24

(poly-eval 0 (list 3 4 6 9 7))
=> 7

(poly-eval 2 (list 1 1 0 1 1 0))
=> 54
```

Comment: Hello oscar, If i wanted to use the second option where you start n in (sub1 (length numlist)) and decrease it at each iteration, how woukd I do so. I am confused.

Comment: @loren I can help you, but that's no reason to remove the accept check mark, that's just rude.

Comment: Sorry I apologize Oscar won't do it again. You have been very helpful by the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Build power coefficient and unknown list than use map function.

```
; 2*3^1+4*3^0
; input is 3 and '(2 4)
; we need '(3 3) '(2 4) '(1 0)
; use map expt build '(3^1 3^0)
; use map * build '(2*3^1 4*3^0)
; use foldr + 0 sum up

(define (poly-eval x coefficient-ls)
  (local ((define power-ls (reverse (build-list (length coefficient-ls) values)))
          (define unknown-ls (build-list (length coefficient-ls) (λ (i) x))))
    (foldr + 0 (map * coefficient-ls (map expt unknown-ls power-ls)))))
```